# dataservice error is not resolving to

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

One of the many issues I'm running into is this error:

> Type 'DataService' has no member 'dataService'

I've been looking but I can't find anything definitive. Your assistance is a appreciated. I'm not sure what the issue is. I thought at first the service was changed to database but that wasn't correct either unless I'm completely wrong.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class UserFeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "userpost-items")

    var userpost = [UserPost]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // observeEventType is called whenever anything changes in the Firebase - new Jokes or Votes.
        // It's also called here in viewDidLoad().
        // It's always listening.

        DataService.dataService.USERPOST_REF.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            // The snapshot is a current look at our jokes data.
            self.userposts = []

            if let snapshots = snapshot?.children.allObjects as? [FDataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshots {
                    // Make our jokes array for the tableView.

                    if let postDictionary = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        let userpost = UserPost(key: key!, dictionary: postDictionary)

                        // Items are returned chronologically, but it's more fun with the newest jokes first.

                        self.userpost.insert(userpost, at: 0)
                    }
                }
            }

            // Be sure that the tableView updates when there is new data.

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userpost.count
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let userpost = self.userpost[indexPath.row]

        // We are using a custom cell.
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UserPostCellTableViewCell") as? UserPostTableViewCell {
            // Send the single user post to configureCell() in UserPostCellTableViewCell.
            cell.configureCell(userpost: userpost)

            return cell
        } else {
            return UserPostTableViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message you get?

Comment: Below is the error message I get when I try to run the sim.  Type 'DataService' has no member 'dataService'

Comment: Why are you doing this *DataService.dataService.*? The class ref should just be defined initally as *var ref: DatabaseReference!* and then later on in maybe viewDid load *self.ref = Database.database().reference()* and then throughout the rest of the class simply define the path you want to observe like *let postRef = self.ref.child("posts")*. You should also consider updating to Firebase 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a comment but actual code will more clearly articulate the pattern I suggest. There are 100 other ways to do this. (Note: Swift 4, Firebase 4)

```
class UserFeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    var userpost = [UserPost]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.ref = Database.database().reference()
    }

    func loadPosts() {
       let postRef = self.ref.child("posts")
       postRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
          self.userposts = []
          ...
    }
```

Comment: like I said I'm a noob and using tutorials, google to learn (need to buy a book).  I'm very thankful for you taking your time to help me out.  BTW, when I place the  postRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in ... it comes up with an error of ... Argument labels '(_:, with:, _:)' do not match any available overloads....

Comment: @limskey Yes, that is a valid error. Note that I mentioned using Swift 4 and *Firebase 4* - you are using an older version of Firebase where the functions are different. You should really upgrade at this point. Once you understand this code, if it helped then please remember to accept it so it can help others!

Comment: hey is there a book or tutorial you’d recommend for me to learn?  I’m tired of trying to find online tutorials on older programming language such as swift 3. Thank you again!

Comment: @limskey There is quote a bit of content available for swift 3 but really, Swift 4 is current and really the way to go. Same thing with Firebase  - get the current version and focus on that.